# Powerquery - Converting single column information having column names and values to table

Tags: transform, powerquery

I have a data in a single column as under

CName1
CName2
CName3
.
.
.
row1 col1 value1
row1 col2 value2
row1 col2 value3
.
.
.
row2 col1 value4
row2 col2 value5
row2 col3 value6
.
.
.
row3 col1 value7
row3 col2 value8
row3 col3 value9
.
.
.
.

What I would like to have is

CName1
CName2
CName3
.....
.....
.....
Value1
value2
value3
.....
.....
.....
Value4
value5
value6
.....
.....
.....
Value7
value8
value9
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....

How can this be achieved ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there any upper limit on the number of columns that might be created? Will there always be at least one empty row between groups?  Please show what you have tried.

Comment: the items are delimited by spaces?

Comment: @horseyride I'm thinking maybe the groups in the source data really just have the "value" parameter, and the row/column locations are not actually there.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are right. Sorry for confusion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method:

***Assumptions***

- The positional entries in each data row are not really there

  - *if they are, we would modify the algorithm*
- All column headers are in the first group
- each group is separated by at least one empty row
- each group's columns start with the first (but they don't all have to have the same number of columns)

*Please read the code comments, and explore the Applied Steps window, to understand the algorithm*

**M Code**
***edited** to remove hard-coded column names from last line*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//add shifted column
    shifted = Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") &    
                    {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type"[Column1])},
                type table[Column1=text, shiftedCol1 =text]),

//create a column which adds an index number at the first row of each group
//then fill down to create a column on which to group
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(shifted, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "grouper", each if [Column1] <> null and [shiftedCol1] = null then [Index] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Columns",{"grouper"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"shiftedCol1"}),

//remove the empty rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each ([Column1] <> null)),

//group by the "grouper" column
//then transpose each sub table
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"grouper"}, {
        {"transpose", each Table.Transpose(Table.SelectColumns(_,"Column1"))}
        }),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"grouper"}),

//combine the grouped subtables, and promote the headers
    comb = Table.Combine(#"Removed Columns2"[transpose]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(comb, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

***Edit***
If, as implied in your comments, there really are NO blank rows between the data sets, but you know the number of columns in the final result,

- hard code the number of columns (or set it as a parameter)
- change how to construct the "grouper" column by doing an IntegerDivide on the Index column, instead of the formula I used in the above.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="dataTable"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Data", type text}}),

//hard coded number of columns
    numCols = 3,

//add grouper
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "grouper", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], numCols), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Index"}),

//group by the "grouper" column
//then transpose each sub table
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"grouper"}, {
        {"transpose", each Table.Transpose(Table.SelectColumns(_,"Data"))}
        }),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"grouper"}),

//combine the grouped subtables, and promote the headers
    comb = Table.Combine(#"Removed Columns2"[transpose]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(comb, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: kudos for deciphering

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Hi Ron,  This code works fine with given assumptions. I needed to be more elaborate with my situation (1) The M code has hard coded column names (Cname1, Cname2...), can that be picked up from the data rather than hard coding in code. (2) I can know how many variables (Columns) are there , we may not have a blank line between groups. Sample column (data,name,age,city,John,33,New York,Jane,21,Toronto,Tom,33,Delhi,Tim,55,London) ',' indicates new row. In this data I have 3 columns, In another data I might have 5 columns..... Sorry to be bothering. I got lost. Thanks for the details.

Comment: @PrasannaDhakephalkar With regard to the hard-coded column names, that was an oversight. Change that line to read `#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), each {_, type text}))`.  I will edit my answer to show that.

Comment: @PrasannaDhakephalkar Have also added code assuming a known (hard-coded) number of columns; and no blank lines between the data sets.  That only changes how you need to construct the "grouper" column, but the basic algorithm remains the same.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The modified one works like a charm, Thanks. It has solved my current situation.. Right now I just pasted the M Code and went ahead. However I will study your magical code. Thanks Once Again.